# BehaviourSubject.getValue() returning default values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I am fairly new to angular. I have two components namely header and profile component. The header component handles the login functionality and maintains two information- the user details which is json object and a isLoggedIn which is a boolean that saves current state of login. The general layout of the profile page is-

```
<header-component>
<profile-component>
```

Now since the header component handles the login. I want to avoid writing the logic for getting userDetails and the isLoggedIn status again for profile component. So i decided writing a shared service called profile service so that i can upload userDetails and isLogged from header and access that info in the profile component. The input in the loginlogout method comes from the header component.

SharedService code -

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from './https.service';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, of as observableOf } from 'rxjs';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BaseService } from './base.service';

@Injectable()
export class ProfileServices{
    constructor(){};

    userDetailsBS = new BehaviorSubject<any>('original value');
    userDetails= this.userDetailsBS.asObservable();
    isLoggedIn:boolean;

    loginlogout(userDetails:any , isLoggedIn:boolean){
        this.userDetails=userDetails;
        this.userDetailsBS.next(this.userDetails);
        console.log("Value of user details set in profile service",this.userDetails); //debug
        console.log(".getValue() method:",this.userDetailsBS.getValue()); //debug
        this.isLoggedIn=isLoggedIn;
    }

    getUserDetails(){
        
        return this.userDetailsBS.getValue();
    }
    
}
```

Post login from the header-component.ts i call the loginlogout method in the profile service to set the values. I also tried to access the value passed to the shared Service using the getUserDetails which shows that the userDetails object is passed correctly to the shared service.

The issue arises when i try to access the data from the profile component-

```
export class ProfileT1Component implements OnInit {
    
    userDetails:any;
    constructor(
        public profileService: ProfileServices){
          this.profileService.userDetails.subscribe((result)=>{
            console.log(result);
            this.userDetails=result;
            console.log("received user details in profile component constructor: ", this.userDetails);
          })
    
      }
    }
```

the result still shows "original value" and not the updated value. Is this wrong approach altogether or am i handling the observables incorrectly. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You definitely do not want `this.userDetails=userDetails;`. You only want to next the behaviour subject (preferably this should be private). The observable is only for getting the value and bs.next will do that automatically. The function `getUserDetails` is not needed.

Comment: Hi i added the getUserDetails method to see if i am able to set the value in the profileservices, which i am able to because console.log displays the json object. The res while subscribing however still shows 'original value' and not the json in the profile component ie.

Comment: could it be a synchronisation issue ie. i am subscribing in the profile component before the observable emits the changed value?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a couple of changes in your service to make it work. Add `providedIn: root` and remove all declarations from other modules. Secondly, you do not need `this.userDetailsBS.asObservable()` and you can use the subscribe directly on `userDetailsBS`. Your code will look something like the following.

Service:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProfileServices {
    constructor() {}

    userDetailsBS = new BehaviorSubject<any>('original value');
    isLoggedIn: boolean;

    loginlogout(userDetails: any, isLoggedIn: boolean) {
        this.userDetailsBS.next(userDetails);
        this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn;
    }

    getUserDetails() {
        return this.userDetailsBS.getValue();
    }
}
```

Component:

```
export class ProfileT1Component implements OnInit {
    userDetails: any;
    constructor(public profileService: ProfileServices) {
        this.profileService.userDetailsBS.subscribe((result) => {
            console.log(result);
            this.userDetails = result;
            console.log('received user details in profile component constructor: ', this.userDetails);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The observable should be kept (and the behaviour subject be private) to make the bs read only to the outside and new values only emittable through functions of the service. Currently any old component could do `profileService.userDetailsBS.next(...)`. If you are the only person to work with this, that may not be a problem, but in general that is a better pattern (e.g. side effects in the service functions will not be performed if the next value is passend in directly).

Comment: oh makes sense, but for some reason its breaking with the observable approach, is there a way to remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

the implementation seems to be OK

(except you should make the BehaviorSubject private and expose only the observable)

probably you have multiple instance of the service.

try to add  :

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

and remove the service declaration from all the modules provider array

https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Comment: Hi i tried your approach, it didnt solve the issue. Upon subscription to the observable the console.log(res) still shows 'original value' and not the json object.

Comment: It's ok to receive 'original value' at the moment of the subscription because is BS return the last emitted value(or default) but after calling loginlogout from another component did you receive the new value?

Comment: the header component calls the loginlogout method which sets isLoggedIn and userDetails.The getUserDetails method console logs the input implicity when received. The profile service is receiving the json. The profile component is called only after that. Since subscription is happening in the constructor and called only once its not reflecting the changed value. console.log(res) is displaying original value only.

Comment: are you 100% sure that the instance of the service in the component that call the loginlogout is the same of the component that subscribe to the observable?
since in the moment you subscribe the value of the observable  is already changed you should receive immediately the new value